# json_decode does not return array in php

Tags: php, json

I am facing with a problem, when I am trying to parse json returns from server into array in php. Here is my code ...

```
<?php
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');  
    $url = 'http://localhost/busexpress/api/v1/mobile_user_register/mobile_user_register/retrieve.json';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    //$data="'".$data."'";
    echo $data;
    curl_close($ch);

    //$trimspace = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $data); 
    //echo $trimspace;

    $jdata = json_decode($data, true);
    print_r $jdata; 

?>
```

This is the json after trimming space. I also want to convert it int array with json_decode() but no result return. I think this json is valid. And suggestion pls. This is my firstly trying to feed web service from server.

Thanks

```
 '{
"status": "1",
"user": [        
    {
        "id": "27",
        "name": "kktt",
        "phone_no": "1239293",
        "activate_code": "0d08ed",
        "deposit": "0",
        "created": "2015-06-0316:35:08",
        "updated": "1110-11-3000:00:00",
        "status": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "28",
        "name": "kktt",
        "phone_no": "1239293",
        "activate_code": "fb4876",
        "deposit": "0",
        "created": "2015-06-0316:37:14",
        "updated": "1000-01-0100:00:00",
        "status": "0"
    }
  ]
}'
```

----------Edit---------

As your suggestion I comment trimming space and correct json format. And echo $data; .....

```
{
"status": "1",
"user": [        
    {
        "id": "27",
        "name": "kktt",
        "phone_no": "1239293",
        "activate_code": "0d08ed",
        "deposit": "0",
        "created": "2015-06-0316:35:08",
        "updated": "1110-11-3000:00:00",
        "status": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "28",
        "name": "kktt",
        "phone_no": "1239293",
        "activate_code": "fb4876",
        "deposit": "0",
        "created": "2015-06-0316:37:14",
        "updated": "1000-01-0100:00:00",
        "status": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

In decoding array doesn't have any data.

```
 $jdata = json_decode($data, true);
 print_r $jdata; 
 echo "user status -> ". $jdata["status"];
```

when I copy that json and hard code in a string, decode it again, it works for me. please see my testing code....

```
$data =' {"status":"1","mobile_user":[{"id":"1","name":"saa","phone_no":"09978784963","activate_code":"","deposit":"0","created":"2015-05-29 00:00:00","updated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","status":"1"},{"id":"3","name":"ttr","phone_no":"090930499","activate_code":"","deposit":"0","created":"2015-06-01 00:00:00","updated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","status":"0"}]}';
$data = json_decode($data,true);
$status = $data['status'];
$mobile_user = $data['mobile_user'];
$id = $mobile_user[0]["id"];
$name = $mobile_user[0]["name"];
echo "id -> ". $id ."<br>";
echo "name -> ". $name;
```

Any suggestion pls!

Answer (score 3):

I think your json is malformed. Remove `$data="'".$data."'";`

You can check [json error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) if any.

And `$trimspace = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $data);` is needless.

Comment: `$jdata` is null? What say http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php?

Comment: thank http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php, this link helps me, the error I got is json syntax error, but still solving.

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode` usually returns an `object`, so I don't think your code is wrong here.

```
$arrayObject = new ArrayObject($object);
$array = $arrayObject->getArrayCopy();
```

This is how you can convert it to an `array`. It works in PHP 5.3+

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $jdata = json_decode($trimspace, true);
     print_r($jdata);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your json is malformed. Remove the '' from the beginning and the end of your file. The contents of $data should look like this:

```
{
"status": "1",
"user": [        
    {
        "id": "27",
        "name": "kktt",
        "phone_no": "1239293",
        "activate_code": "0d08ed",
        "deposit": "0",
        "created": "2015-06-0316:35:08",
        "updated": "1110-11-3000:00:00",
        "status": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "28",
        "name": "kktt",
        "phone_no": "1239293",
        "activate_code": "fb4876",
        "deposit": "0",
        "created": "2015-06-0316:37:14",
        "updated": "1000-01-0100:00:00",
        "status": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Second $jdata is an associative array. You cannot print its contents with echo. Instead do

```
print_r($jdata);
```

Third you don't need to remove spaces. Do that in the script that produces the json, otherwise just parse the json with the spaces directly.

Comment: @ Bjarnstroem, thank for your answer, I edited my question again, could you give me a favor of checking it agin.

Comment: @SAWAUNG Hey, I suggest you read the PHP documentation before posting here... print_r needs () around the parameters. So don't write print_r $jdata; but print_r($jdata);